# Norm of a linear functional on $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to calculate norm of the following operator

$T:C\left([0,1], \mathbb{K}\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$.

(On the domain we have a supremum norm - $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.)

$T\left(f\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{2^n}f(t_n) $,

where $\{t_n\}\subset\left[0,1\right], \ t_n\neq t_m $ for $n\neq m$ and $\xi_n\in \mathbb{S}^1$.

One can easily check that

$\|Tf\|_{\mathbb{K}}=\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{2^n}f(t_n)\right|\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{f(t_n)}{2^n}\right|\le \|f\|_{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\|f\|_{\infty}$.

If $\{t_n\}$ has only finitely many accumulation points in $[0,1]$ then one can easily construct function, on which the norm is realized. But how to do it in the other case ? For example if $t_n=t(n)$, where $t:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is a bijection ?

Comment: What's $\mathbb K$? Either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Why should the norm be realized ? Your construction certainly gives that the norm is greater than $\Sigma _1^N {1\over 2^n}$ for every $N$...

Comment: @Thomas: Why would you say this? I don't find it obvious.

Comment: Your proof says that $T$ is is the limit for the opertaor norm of the sequence of operators $T_N(f)=\sum _1^N {\xi_n\over 2^n}f(t_n)$, or I dont understand something ?

Comment: $\{t_n\}$ and $\{\xi_n\}$ are fixed. $T$ is defined as a sum of a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{2^n}f(t_n)$. It is well-defined since $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$.  If $\{t_n\}$ has finitely many accumulation points then we can explicitly construct continuous $f$ s.th. $\| T f\|=\|f\|_{\infty}$. W.L.O.G. : There is only one accumulation point. Then we can find open interval $I$ s.th. there is only finitely many elements of $\{t_n\}$ in $[0,1]\setminus I$. Hence we can can defined $f=0$ on $I$ and on the $\{t_n \ : \ t_n\not\in I\}$ we define $f$ s.th. the sum is equal to $1$.